# how to fix supplying multiple axes to axis is no longer supported error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing, neighbors, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Home\Desktop\result-messidor.csv')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)
df.dropna(['id'], 1, inplace=True)
x = np.array(df.dropna(['class'], 1, axis=1))
y = np.array(df['class'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)
```

I am trying to determine the accuracy using SVM algorithm 
but I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/rrrr/Arwa1.py", line 10, in <module>
    df.dropna(['id'], 1, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\enviroment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4734, in dropna
    raise TypeError("supplying multiple axes to axis is no longer supported.")
TypeError: supplying multiple axes to axis is no longer supported.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be directly related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20987. See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, please write keyward argument in dropna function such as;

```
df.dropna(subset=['id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html